# Some stdperiph files are grayed in project explorer in eclipse (stm32) Why?

Tags: c++, eclipse, stm32

I created new "Cross ARM GCC" c++ project via eclipse wizard, but some stdperiph .c files are greyed? :( 
Why? 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tje7E.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means the directory and/or files are being filtered from the source locations in eclipse. 
Do this if you wanna get rid of it..

**(Project) Properties ->C/C++ General ->Paths and Symbols ->Source Location Tab ->Edit Filter... ->Remove**